# How to navigate to TabBar ViewController on click of button on popover ViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have TabBarController project, with navigation bar. On navigation bar I have popover on right `BarButtonItem`. On that popover `ViewController`  I have one button. On that button click I want to move to any `TabBarController`.

I tried with

```
tababarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

But view is not switching

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will dismiss popover and call delegate method
From popover viewcontroller in main view controller 
And then set the selected index of a toolbar   in your delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

setSelectedIndex should work right.

Maybe you are not getting correct reference of your UITabBarController and while checking, you might get it nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PopupviewController {

weak var delegate: NavigateViewDelegate?

func buttonPress () {
   delegate?.navigate()
 }  
}
protocol NavigateViewDelegate : class {
      func navigate()
}
class TabBarViewController :NavigateViewDelegate {

  func navigate() {
    tababarController.selectedIndex = 1   
  }
}
```

Comment: class TabBarViewController :NavigateViewDelegate  which type of class is this?